# Import a variable from a function of python script into another python script

Tags: python

Maybe I'm asking a question that was already answered but even if I searched I couldn't find a solution.
I've a main script called "script.py". The relevant content is:

```
def file_select():

    root = tk.Tk()

    root.withdraw()


    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select a file !!")
    print(file_path)
    bankFile = pd.read_excel(r'{}'.format(file_path), usecols='{}'.format(column),
                                 skiprows=[i for i in range(int(rowsa))])

    bankFile.dropna(inplace=True)
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

    pd.set_option('max_rows', None)

....


if __name__ == '__main__':

    menu()


    conn.close()
```

The whole script is parsing some columns from a selected excel file and make some arithmetic operations.
I've another script called "db_food.py". It's interacting with sqlite database and with the help of few other functions, does some calculations like calculate spendings for food or save the sum into database etc.
My question is: How can I import and use "bankFile" variable defined in file_select function into "db_food.py" ?

PS: When I use "import script" or "from script import file_select", a file selection dialogbox is shown twice. So I'm asked to select the excel file twice. But I only want to import "bankFile" variable as it is defined in "script.py" and use its content.

Comment: You may want to do a basic Python tutorial. A function's local variable are local to that function. They only exist *during* execution of the function, and are not unique – meaning they cannot be addressed from "outside" the function. If you want to use ``bankFile`` outside the function, reconsider your design – either ``return`` from the function, or use a separately existing data structure, i.e. a class.

Comment: Finally, I changed the structure by creating a class and put all functions inside it.
Then,created a directory where I moved all database related scripts so that I can import them inside main script. All works now...

Answer (score 0):

That variable is scoped to that function, so as it stands you cannot import it elsewhere. There are also no "tricks" like storing it as a global outside of the scope and importing that, as the value would be whatever you initialized it as (possible `None`) until the function `file_select()` is run. Unless you want to considerably restructure the code, perhaps persisting object as a `pickle`d binary in something like Redis is an option. Otherwise, you could consider making this a `staticmethod` inside class, defining and using the class in `script.py` and then instantiating an object to use the static method in `db_food.py`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So, as _"bankFile"_ is defined in a function inside _"script.py"_, there is no possibility to import it in _db_food.py_ like :

`from script import file_select
...

data=file_select.bankFile`